# Excel VBA can't find files in path

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a strange problem with Excel VBA on Mac.
The code below worked once with 3 files. On a second run I removed the `UserFileName = Dir()` command to see what happens. Which lead to Excel killing itself and I had to force quit it. After restoring the code I can't make it work, giving me a

> 1004 Error (Object or Method not found)

in the row with `Set UserWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(UserFileName)`. It seems Excel can't find any files there, but there are the same 3 files as before.

The loop C&P's data from the files into the last row of my master sheet.

```
'Specifing file directory.'
Dim UserFileName As String
UserFileName = Dir("/Users/AccountName/Documents/Reporting/Data/Import/*")

'Start Loop for import.'
Do While Len(UserFileName) > 0
UserFileName = Dir()

Dim UserWorkbook As Workbook
Set UserWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(UserFileName)

...

Loop
```

Answer (score -1):

The path mentioned is not in the correct format.
Put something like:
    `UserFileName = Dir("C:\Users\name\Downloads\*")`

Comment: I'm using MacOS, that's the correct Path from "Get Info" and the way I have to grab it as I understand it.

Comment: I have no idea for Mac, because this code is working fine on windows. Most probably the issue is with the path.

Comment: Hm when I use the full path with file name instead of *, it does not work either. I tried with a different file and no success. But the first time when I wrote the macro, it worked perfectly fine.